# Dashes in property name not getting NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, linkedin-api, erb

I'm using the Linkedin gem to pull profile information for RoR 3.

- Gem: https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin
- API Doc: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#positions

Everything works except when I get to a property with a dash in the name.

`<%=position.title %>` displays correctly but`<%= position.start-date %>` return a `NoMethodError` in `Users#show` - `undefined method start`.

I've tried different operations like "startDate", "start_date", quotes around "start-date" but none have worked.

Is there a proper way to escape the dash/hyphen in the property name?

Comment: It was my fault. I had an older version of the gem.

Answer (score 0):

The expression in your ERB will be parsed as subtracting the value of the date variable from the result of a call to the start() method of the position object. Hyphens aren't valid in identifiers within Ruby.

I'm not familiar enough with the LinkedIn gem to suggest a solution, except to say that since it's based on an XML API, you should look for a way to manually pull data out of a tag pair. Most similar gems offer such a method. Also, this is a great case for using IRB as an exploratory tool: fire up an IRB session and see what happens when you call position.methods, after properly creating the position variable of course. My guess would be that you'll see something in that list which suggests an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it returns a Hashie::Mash which converts keys, with a few extra rules:
https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin/blob/master/lib/linked_in/mash.rb

You said you'd already tried `position.start_date` right?  That should work.  But if not, have you tried `position['start-date']` or `position['start_date']` one of those two should also work, since it's a Mash.